# Java RMI: setup-method returns immediatly and RMI threads aren't created

Tags: java, rmi

I'm trying to set up a simple RMI server which is bound to the registry for clients to fetch for all further communication. I am using the code below:

```
public class RMIServer implements ServerInterface {

    static Registry reg;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws NoSuchObjectException {
        //Registry reg;
        try {
            reg = LocateRegistry.createRegistry(1099);
            System.out.println("Registry created.");
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            System.err.println("Registry already existed.");
            return;
        }
        ServerInterface server = new RMIServer();
        ServerInterface stub;
        try {
            stub = (ServerInterface)UnicastRemoteObject.exportObject(server, 0);
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            System.err.println("Could not create stub.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            return;
        }
        try {
            reg.rebind("server", stub);
            System.out.println("Server bound to registry.");
        } catch (RemoteException ex) {
            System.err.println("Could not bind server to registry.");
            ex.printStackTrace();
            //UnicastRemoteObject.unexportObject(server, true);
            return;
        }
    }
    ...
}
```

This works perfectly fine when testing on my local machine and I was able to establish connections between (local) clients and the server. The main method above will not exit until I terminate it manually, which is the expected behavior. My local machine (Win8) runs Java 1.7.0_17 64-bit.

Now when I execute the same code as above on a Ubuntu 12.04 Server with OpenJDK (version 1.7.0_55 64-bit), the main method and whole JVM immediately exit and the RMI threads aren't running. No error messages are printed; I only get the messages about the registry being created and the server being bound to the registry. Obviously clients then cannot connect, as no RMI process is running on the server.

As far as I am aware, the main method should not automatically exit as long as there are exported objects which I have not unexported again. Yet it does on one of my machines.

Does anyone have an idea what I am missing here?

Thank you!

**Update 1:** 
(Sorry, very busy lately and didn't get the chance to look at this further until now). The problem still persists with Java 6, 7, OpenJDK and Sun's version, even after updating to Ubuntu 14.04.

However, I managed to reproduce the issue on a completely different machine hosted in the cloud, also running Ubuntu server 14.04 x64 (although pretty much entirely clean, apart from the java installation). I'm still trying to figure out how exactly to reproduce it, though (will update when I know more).

The problem vanishes (temporarily, it seems) when rebooting the system, on both machines. 
For completeness also: curiously, with the system log level set to FINE or FINEST the code suddenly behaves as expected. I'm still stumped.

Comment: I cannot offer any real insight here apart from the fact that I have encountered multiple (serious) issues with the OpenJDK Java implementations in the paste. If you can switch to the Sun / Oracle JRE's (even if it's only to test) chances are your problem will automagically solve itself.

Comment: Thanks - I've switched to Oracle Java, making sure to remove OpenJDK from the machine - with the same results. It also makes no difference on which machine I compile the source code; it works on one machine but not on the other.

Comment: I just tried your code on an ubuntu 12.04 with java-6-openjdk-i386 and it behaves as you expect, i.e. the process does not exit and starts listening on two ports (registry and bound object). Full logging of RMI might help, as suggest in another comment: see http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/technotes/guides/rmi/sunrmiproperties.html for details.

Comment: Whatever the cause, you can fix this once and for all by putting a sleep() inside an infinite loop after the setup code.

Answer (score 0):

Make the 'reg' variable static. Otherwise it is liable to GC and DGC which will unexport it, which in turn will lead to DGC of the server and its unexporting, which in turn leads to socket closure and listening thread exit.

Comment: Interesting, could you elaborate why the reg variable would go out of scope and be eligible for GC?

Comment: @ChristopheD You've just said it yourself. It's presently a local variable, so it goes out of scope when main() exits, so it becomes eligible for GC.

Comment: I get that, but welll I guess it depends on what the `...` in the code snippet above hides... I would still find it 'strange' if some code worked (seemingly) `by accident` on a specific Java implementation, and does not on another (e.g. OpenJDK), strictly caused by differing GC implementations... scoping rules should be identical (if not, there would be more issues :))

Comment: @EJP Thanks for the suggestion, I've tried making reg a static class variable instead of a local one (see edit) - unfortunately the behavior hasn't changed. On the Ubuntu machine the method still immediately exits (now running with Oracle Java).

Comment: @ChristopheD Nobody said anything about the the scoping rules being different. Of course they aren't. This code is wrong on all Java versions, unless there is a sleep in the '...'.

Comment: @Jocbe In that case you're going to have to tell us what's in the '...'.

Comment: I realized I was missing a bracket in the initial post, sorry - now corrected. There is nothing more in the main method, the "..." represents the remote methods part of the server, which my clients are eventually supposed to talk to. I assume that isn't relevant here, though (tell me if I'm wrong).

Comment: OK. Can you run your program with *all* the RMI logging system properties mentioned on both the RMI system properties and Sun RMI system properties pages and see if anything exciting pops out.

Comment: I set all the logging properties I could find to true and lowered some loglevels to FINEST as well; When running the code I get no additional output. (Unless some of it goes into some files I don't know about?).

I did make an interesting observation, though. If I start the JVM with a custom logging.properties file, in which I set the loglevel to FINER or FINEST, the whole thing suddenly works and the JVM does not exit, as I would expect. Set the loglevel back to FINE or INFO and the old odd behavior is back. I'm a bit baffled as to why the loglevel should impact this at all.